# Magento Product Image Import selection store-wise not working

Tags: magento-1.9, multistore, import, product-images, csv

I have installed Magento CE-1.9.2.4 in my local system, and created two stores namely "personal"(default) and "business".

Now I want to import a product's images in such a way that both store should show different images for same products in Frontend and Backend.

I am using Admin > System > ImportExport > Import for importing only product-images.

Below is the csv file I am using to import images store-wise.

```
sku,store,websites,image,small_image,thumbnail,image_label,small_image_label,thumbnail_label,_media_image,_media_attribute_id,_media_is_disabled,_media_position,_media_lable
478,personal,base,/new_products/sample1.png,/new_products/sample1.png,/new_products/sample1.png,Test Image,Test Small Image,Test Thumbnail,/new_products/sample1.png,88,1,1,Test 1
,business,business,/new_products/newImg.png,/new_products/newImg.png,/new_products/newImg.png,Test Image,Test Small Image,Test Thumbnail,/new_products/newImg.png,88,1,1,Test 1 Forhandler
```

Image upload works fine, but the image selection store-wise doesn't work at all. Both stores take the default store's image selection, which is not desired for me at all.

Can anyone let me know what could be wrong ?

Comment: Is your issue solved?

Comment: Did you ever use magmi?